# Not able to build query correctly using the find_by_sql method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following query where I am trying to fetch department table data based on multiple department ids using `IN` clause but the query that I see in the `Rails` server log is incorrect and hence the data fetching fails. Problem with quotes.

I tried two different options here but both of them fails because of either missing quotes or extra quotes.

**OPTION 1 (ADDING QUOTES DURING CSV CONVERSION)**

```
@depts = current_user.depts             
puts @depts                 # prints    IT Account Finance

# converting to CSV string here
@dept_ids_csv = @depts.gsub(" ", "','")     
puts @dept_ids_csv          # prints    IT','Account','Finance


@dept_data = Department.find_by_sql(["select * from departments a where a.dept_id in (?)", @dept_ids_csv])
```

*Expected Query Log:*

```
select * from departments a where a.dept_id in ('IT','Account','Finance')
```

*Actual Query Log Generated (for soem reason appends extra quotes automatically) - FAILS:*

```
select * from departments a where a.dept_id in ('IT'',''Account'',''Finance')
```

**OPTION 2 (REMOVING THE QUOTES DURING CSV CONVERSION)**

```
@depts = current_user.depts             
puts @depts                 # prints    IT Account Finance

# converting to CSV string here 
@dept_ids_csv = @depts.gsub(" ", ",")   
puts @dept_ids_csv          # prints    IT,Account,Finance


@dept_data = Department.find_by_sql(["select * from departments a where a.dept_id in (?)", @dept_ids_csv])
```

*Expected Query Log:*

```
select * from departments a where a.dept_id in ('IT','Account','Finance')
```

*Actual Query Log Generated (missing quotes in the IN clause) - FAILS:*

```
select * from departments a where a.dept_id in ('IT,Account,Finance')
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the string into an array and passing it to a where clause.

```
@dept_data = Department.where(dept_id: @depts.split(" "))
```

Comment: The query that I posted above is not the original query as the original one is more complex. I have simplified the query in order to explain the actual problem. Is it possible for you to provide a solution using `find_by_sql` method ?

Comment: No worries. Got it working by putting in `@depts.split(" ")`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How about converting string into array by `.split(' ')`?

Example:

```
@emails = ['spree@example.com', 'test@gmail.com']

User.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM spree_users WHERE email IN (?)", @emails])
```

gives

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IN ('spree@example.com','test@gmail.com')`